# aapt and :app:processDebugRecources errors

Tags: android-studio, resources, aapt, aero-glass

I got problems with aapt and :app:processDebugRecources. How I can get these errors go away? I did add only `compile 'madgaze.x5_gesture:development-kit:1.1.7.beta'` to build.gradle. All other things in project is untouched

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.minttu.qr_codereader"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'madgaze.x5_gesture:development-kit:1.1.7.beta'
}
```

and here is all errors I got:

```
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Button not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Caption not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display2 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display3 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display4 not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Inverse not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle not found.
Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title not found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Gradle console shows this text for those errors:

```
* `What went wrong:`

    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
```

What I have tried so far:
add `android.enableAapt2=false` to gradle.properties and clean project from build menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that library requires compileSdkVersion at least 23.